# component mounting before fetch is complete, resulting in failed propTypes

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a tour website. The basic structure here is that I have the tour page, and on the tour page is a component that handles booking times. When mounted, TourPage fetches the available start times from the db and ships that data down as props.

I am able to receive this data and send it down, but the deeper component gives back a propTypes error, saying the data is undefined. When I console log out (from parent) the value of this data, it logs 3 times: first, it is an empty array. The second and third time, the data is there.

Odd thing is that the propType error appears chronologically AFTER my console.log showing the actual data. I have also added logic to the TourPage to return a Spinner if the availableStartTimes array is empty. I fully expect that no children components will be mounted until all data has arrived. This does not seem to be the case.

Here is some relevant code (edited for brevity):

```
const ExperienceDetailContainer = () => {

  //a function that cleans the fetched data. returns an array
  const availableStartTimes = getTimesForCurrentDate(experienceDate, detail.availabilities)

  //fetch request to get available start times
  const getExperienceAvailabilities = () => {
    api.post('/GetExperienceAvailabilities', { experienceid: experienceId })
    .then(result => {
      const availabilities = result.d
      updateExperience(availabilities)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err)
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getExperienceAvailabilities()
  }, [])

  if (availableStartTimes.length < 1) {
    return <Spinner />
  }

  return <ExperienceDetail {...{ availableStartTimes, experienceDate }} />

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  detail: fromResource.getDetail(state, 'experience'),
  experienceDate: state.userSelections.experienceDate,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  readDetail: (apiRequestParams) => dispatch(resourceDetailReadRequest('experience', { apiRequestParams })),
  updateExperience: (availabilities) => dispatch(updateExperience('experience', availabilities))
})
```

here is getTimesForCurrentDate helper function:

```
export const getTimesForCurrentDate = (date, availabilities) => {
    if (!availabilities) {
        return []
    }
    const rawTimes = availabilities[formattedDateWithoutTime(date)]
    const properTimes = rawTimes.map(rawTime => {
        return convertTimeFromRawToProper(rawTime)
    })
    return properTimes
}
```

here is the propTypes for BookCard component

```
BookCard.propTypes = {
    availableStartTimes: T.arrayOf(T.string).isRequired,
}
```

and the reducer for updateExperience

```
 case UPDATE_EXPERIENCE:
      return {
        ...state,
        experience: {
          ...getResourceState(state, resource),
          detail: {
            ...getDetail(state, resource),
            availabilities: payload

          }
        }
      }
```

here is a screenshot of my console to demonstrate the 3 outputs of availableStartTimes, as well as a console.log(availableStartTimes.toString()) placed after the Spinner guard if statement
[image]

Comment: can you show your reducer and propTypes please

Comment: Nothing is standing out to me, is the shape of your array all strings?

Comment: yes they are all strings. Could it have to do with the fact that there is multiple fetching going on? When the component loads, it needs to fetch the tour details, which I do with a saga. Once that data is returned, it is used in getTimesForCurrentDate(). Maybe race conditions?

Comment: It shouldn't matter as long as availableStartTimes is correctly populated. I feel like somehow your guard must be failing to catch all cases and is rendering the component when it shouldn't. Try to put a console log after your spinner return outside the if... stringify it so the array reference doesn't update before the console outputs and see if its somehow passing an incorrect array

Comment: updated post to reflect the screen shot of the console you advised to add. Its an interesting problem, because we can clearly see that the array is formatted as it should be. I can't understand why it's bypassing the Spinner guard

Comment: Can you try putting an else around <ExperienceDetail> ? Don't know why that would help, but it seems to be bypassing the condition

Comment: that oddly seemed to do the trick... I have no idea what just happened, but I am very thankful for your persistence in helping me figure it out. Cheers!